# Javascript on input text change, change div text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change text of one div, when I enter different values into my text input:

EXAMPLE:

```
Input = 1,
DIV TEXT: "rok" //in eng. "year"

Input = 2,
DIV TEXT: "roky"

Input = 3,
DIV TEXT: "roky"

Input = 4,
DIV TEXT: "roky"

Input = 5,
DIV TEXT: "rokov"
```

Default value of my input is 3.

html

```
<input type="text" id="pocetrokov" value="3"><span id="year">roky</span>
```

Js:

```
function rok() {
if(roky==2 || roky==3 || roky==4){
$('#year').html('roky');
  } else if( roky>4 || roky == 0){
$('#year').html('rokov');
  } else if (roky==1){
    $('#year').html('rok');
  }

} 

 $(function () {
 $('select, input').on('keydown blur change', rok);
 });
```

I get this when I change the defalut value:

```
Input = 1,
DIV TEXT ="rokov" instead of "rok"

Input = 2,
DIV TEXT ="rokov" instead of "rok"
```

... etc.

I get the correct value only when I click somehere outside the input

What is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: html is too large to be putted in here. Can you specify what are u searching for in html so I can choose which part of html should i put here?

Comment: LShetty - great, it works, Post it like an answer and I will accept it, If you would like to. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function rok(roky) {
    if(roky==2 || roky==3 || roky==4){
        $('#year').html('roky');
    } else if( roky>4 || roky == 0){
    $('#year').html('rokov');
    } else if (roky==1){
        $('#year').html('rok');
    }
} 

 $(function () {
    $('input').on('keyup blur change', function(){
        rok( $(this).val() );
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Keyup Event instead of other,because value of text field is fetched when you keydown and when key down your actual value thats on variable is the previous value,Not the one that is currently in input field So, the function Works correctly :

```
 $(function () {
 $('input').on('keyup', rok);
 });
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/qnJ82/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Guys why are you complicating it so much with 2 functions?

```
$("html").on("keyup","#pocetrokov",function(){
var roky=parseInt($(this).val());
   if(roky==2 || roky==3 || roky==4){ $('#year').html('roky');}
   else if(roky>4 || roky === 0) { $('#year').html('rokov');}
   else if (roky==1){     $('#year').html('rok');   }
```

});